# How do I determine Zone 2 HR and Wattage without Lactate tests?

Tags: heart-rate, target-heart-rate, lactate-threshold, zone

What does the HR curve look like if wattage is too high?

Also, how does HR/ideal Wattage vary from day to day and with different bikes (Assuming bikes of course)?

Would HR be the same with other forms of exercise?

My current approach is to start with target HR in the low end of a calculated range - reduce "intensity" when HR surpasses this target HR.

In the following sessions, I would increase start wattage and target HR until wattage seems to be too high.